# No option to add user in Moto E3 Power on Android Marshmallow

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, multi-user, motorola-moto-e

It's been a while I tried few options, but I was not able to find how to add users in Moto E3 Power running Android Marshmallow. It is not present in the settings.

[image]

Any way to debug this or to activate this, as Android Marshmallow supports multi-users?

Comment: The Moto E and G series devices with Marshmallow do not have multi-user implemented, the only way to make it work is to flash a custom ROM.

Comment: @acejavelin moto g4 plus has multi user functionality

Comment: Your OEM removed/suppressed this functionality because they found the hardware unsuitable to support more than a single user. It's pretty much a normal thing in low-end devices. If your Android is rooted, try the trick Android One users follow to enable multi-user.

Comment: @acejavelin: thanks for the pointer. Edited answer based on it

Comment: @pkm I was unaware that the G4 had this functionality, I can confirm the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd generation G and 1st and 2nd generation E series devices do not have this functionality (I just fired up my original G and G3 to verify), however my Moto X Pure Edition does have this feature.

Comment: Other sources on the web also confirm that it is not supported on your phone, unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Your device **does not support** multi user mode

See reply by [Senior Moderator](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/MOTO-E-3rd-Gen/One-handed-microscreen/m-p/3463145#M196) in Lenovo forums

> There are many features that are disabled on different phones due to hardware or other reasons. It could be that the GPU can't handle this. It could be that some features are reserved for mid or high end phones.
>
> **Another example is multi-user mode**

(Emphasis supplied)

Sorry about that !

---

On supported Moto devices, you find this option under

- Settings → Device → users → add user
- Another way to find out is to use the search option in settings ( magnifying glass symbol on top right). Just typing  *add* brings up this option, as you can see in first Screenshot
- From the notification bar, it has a user icon at extreme right, clicking on which will give you user options , as in second screenshot

[image]
 [image]

Comment: Also, is there a user icon at the top right of notification shade? I haven't used Moto's implementation of "stock" Android.

Comment: Yes there is icon but on clicking doesn't show add user option ..... also not visible when I type "add"or in the top right corner

Comment: Unfortunately your device doesn't support * multi user* mode

Comment: My device was supporting it but after reset option disappeared.